# Install ros-hydro-rqt failed

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

system: ubuntu 12.04 LTS
ROS version 1.9.54
I try to install ros-hydro-rqt, but failed.

```
sudo apt-get install ros-hydro-rqt
Failed to fetch http:packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/pool/main/r/ros-hydro-rqt/ros-hydro-rqt_0.2.13-0precise-20140130-2154-+0000_amd64.deb  Something wicked happened resolving 'packages.ros.org:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/173222/install-ros-hydro-rqt-failed./) by [MIller](https://answers.ros.org/users/18828/miller/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2014-06-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> Failed to fetch http:packages.ros.org

If this is really a copy/paste, then it would seem the two forward slashes (ie: "//") are missing from the URL. The correct URL is:

```
http://packages.ros.org
```

Perhaps check and make sure that your `sources.list` or `ros-latest.list` contains the correct URL?

---

Edit: apparently the URL was missing the forward slashes due to not being able to post URLs.

Either this is then a transient network error, or something is wrong with the cached APT data. Try doing:

```
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ros-hydro-rqt
```

This might clear things up.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2014-06-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [MIller](https://answers.ros.org/users/18828/miller/) on 2014-06-10**:
I delete the “//” by myself becase my account cann't post content with link.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2014-06-10**:
Ok, well, are you able to do a 'ping packages.ros.org' on the machine where you are getting the error?

**Comment by [MIller](https://answers.ros.org/users/18828/miller/) on 2014-06-10**:
Internate is in good condition, ping time is within 30 ms.

**Comment by [MIller](https://answers.ros.org/users/18828/miller/) on 2014-06-10**:
Err http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/ precise/main ros-hydro-rqt amd64 0.2.13-0precise-20140130-2154-+0000
404  Not Found

**Comment by [MIller](https://answers.ros.org/users/18828/miller/) on 2014-06-10**:
I checked this directory: the coorsponding file has update to
http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/pool/main/r/ros-hydro-rqt/ros-hydro-rqt_0.2.14-0precise-20140311-2004-+0000_amd64.deb
So the system cannnot find it.
But how can I fix this problem?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2014-06-10**:
I'm not sure what could be happening here, but you might want to do a 'sudo apt-get clean', followed by a 'sudo apt-get update'. Then see if you can install your package using 'sudo apt-get install ros-hydro-rqt'.